# JQuery-QueryBuilder não funciona dentro do VueJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, querybuilder

Bom dia, estou tentando utilizar o QueryBuilder do JQuery junto com o VueJs, porém estou obtendo o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo segue o código que esta dando este erro:

```
        this.$refs.builder.queryBuilder({
        filters: [{ id: 1 }] 
    });
```

Anteriormente eu utilizava AngularJs, e funcionava perfeitamente com este código:

```
    angular.element('#builder').queryBuilder({
        filters: [{ id: 1 }] 
    });
```

E também funciona com JQuery:

```
        $('#builder').queryBuilder({
        filters: [{ id: 1 }]
    });
```

O código HTML é esse:

```
 <div id="builder" ref="builder"></div>
```

Alguém sabe o por que de não funcionar no VueJs?

Comment: Não seria mais interessante usar uma ferramenta em Vue ao invés de usar jQuery dentro de um projeto Vue? Ex.: [vue-query-builder](https://github.com/dabernathy89/vue-query-builder).

Comment: Sem contar que `this.$refs.builder` se refere a um elemento HTML e não a um objeto jQuery como você pode estar pensando. Você poderia converter para um objeto jQuery usando `$(this.$refs.builder)` mas não sei se a instância do plugin vai estar vinculada ao objeto.

Comment: Também pensei nisso, mas como temos uma equipe, o pessoal achou melhor continuar com este QueryBuilder, até porque o sistema já conta com outras telas implementadas com ele, e os desenvolvedores já estão acostumados com ele. Apenas esbarrei nesse problema pois estamos fazendo uma migração de AngularJs para VueJs.

Comment: `$(this.$refs.builder).queryBuilder(...)` funcionou?

Comment: Opa, funcionou sim! Muito obrigado! Quer inserir como resposta da pergunta?

Comment: Vou inserir agora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como especificado na [documentação do Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs), `this.$refs` contém referências aos elementos HTML e componentes registrados através da diretiva [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref).

Então se `this.$refs.builder` é uma referência a um elemento HTML, você pode "empacotar" este elemento em um objeto jQuery usando o método [`jQuery(elemento)`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-element).

Após isso basta usar o plugin normalmente.

Segue o código:

```
$(this.$refs.builder).queryBuilder({
    filters: [{ id: 1 }]
})
```